# Solution for small router with no airflow in office

Tags: networking, router, soho

As per title it's a small office with no air circulation....the old router is dead and it's because of overheating I suspect.

It was a budget router and only for one user (without a cooling fan0.....I suspect it will probably be a home/ small office router within a budget price range of 30 euro (34 US Dollars) or so.....typically, these devices do not appear to have fans no matter what manufacturer....

Is the best solution to install a small "desk type fan" beside the router to blow air over the vent holes? It's not the most elegant solution so i'm looking for other ideas....thanks.

Comment: Does it have a usb port?

Comment: If the office has so little airflow that a 20 Watts or so device overheats I pity the person that has to work in that office...

Comment: Add heat sinks to it or a small localized fan on top of it I guess or put it somewhere with better air flow like the wall or something.. How tiny is your office that it is overheating?

Answer (score 1):

You are making an assumption the old router failed because of overheating. Unless you have significant proof that is what caused it, you may be concerned for nothing.

Consumer routers are designed to withstand certain operating temperatures *(since you didn't give any specific model info, I could not look up the operating temperatures)*.  They don't typically have fans because they don't generate a lot of heat and they are designed passively release heat via the builtin heat-sinks.

Using a small fan to create some airflow will not hurt the router and will give you some peace of mind. The only issue, you may need to blow the dust out the router occasionally due to the introduced airflow.